# Spring 3.2 @ResponseBody not working with a Model return value

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

The following mapping was working with Spring 3.1, but is not working with Spring 3.2.
I get a 404 error with an explanation that the table.jsp file is missing. Instead, the "model" should be serialized to json.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/table"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Model table(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") Integer pg) {
        fillListModel(model, pg);
        return model;
    }
```

Is there a way to fix this without any impact to the existing code?

The following code works fine:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/table"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody Model table(Model model, @RequestParam(defaultValue = "1") Integer pg) {
        return new User();
    }
```

So it looks like Spring cannot recognize that the model is returned with a purpose to be turned into json instead to be rendered in a view.

Comment: Is `Model` the Spring class or your custom class?

Comment: The Model is the spring model: org.springframework.ui.Model

Comment: This is still actual problem for `Spring 4.2.x`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a consequence of how Spring 3.2+ (I don't remember how 3.1 does it) handles `@RequestMapping` methods' return values. Spring uses instances of type [`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html) to resolve how the value returned should be handled. Go through the javadoc too see the different types.

When you configure your MVC environment, if you use the default `@EnableWebMVC` or `<mvc:annotation-driven>`, Spring registers these instances in a specific order. This happens in the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#getDefaultReturnValueHandlers()` method as shown below

```
private List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> getDefaultReturnValueHandlers() {
    List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> handlers = new ArrayList<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler>();

    // Single-purpose return value types
    handlers.add(new ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler());
    handlers.add(new ModelMethodProcessor());
    handlers.add(new ViewMethodReturnValueHandler());
    handlers.add(new HttpEntityMethodProcessor(getMessageConverters(), this.contentNegotiationManager));
    handlers.add(new CallableMethodReturnValueHandler());
    handlers.add(new DeferredResultMethodReturnValueHandler());
    handlers.add(new AsyncTaskMethodReturnValueHandler(this.beanFactory));

    // Annotation-based return value types
    handlers.add(new ModelAttributeMethodProcessor(false));
    handlers.add(new RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor(getMessageConverters(), this.contentNegotiationManager));

    // Multi-purpose return value types
    handlers.add(new ViewNameMethodReturnValueHandler());
    handlers.add(new MapMethodProcessor());

    // Custom return value types
    if (getCustomReturnValueHandlers() != null) {
        handlers.addAll(getCustomReturnValueHandlers());
    }

    // Catch-all
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(getModelAndViewResolvers())) {
        handlers.add(new ModelAndViewResolverMethodReturnValueHandler(getModelAndViewResolvers()));
    }
    else {
        handlers.add(new ModelAttributeMethodProcessor(true));
    }

    return handlers;
}
```

When your method returns a value, Spring iterates through these handlers, calling their `supportsReturnType()` method and picking the first it finds that returns `true`.

In this case, the `ModelMethodProcessor` which handles `Model` return values has higher priority (is registered before) the `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` which handles `@ResponseBody`.

As such, you can't return a `Model` and have it be converted to JSON through the `@ResponseBody`. In my opinion, you shouldn't do this at all. The `Model` is accessible to most parts of the `DispatcherServlet` stack and therefore many modules can add/remove attributes which you may not want in the final JSON.

Just use a DTO like you have in your second example.

Comment: Beat me to the punch. You could set up your own list though and thereby define the order of the default handlers as you like.

Comment: @zero Right, you would have to do some custom configuration with the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` bean. I don't think it's worth it.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. @Sotirios, great explanation, exactly what I needed. I will not mess with re-configuring spring, I will go with the DTO approach Sotirios recommends.

Comment: Probably not, but there's a problem for every solution ;)

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: the HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler should work the same way for spring 3.1 (but there was a change from 3.0 to 3.1)

Comment: @Ralph These major changes came in 3.1 then? I can't explain why it works in 3.1 then.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis  http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html Chapter 3.13 New HandlerMethod-based Support Classes For Annotated Controller Processing