# @ResponseBody annotated method do not return Model as JSON Spring 3.2.10

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

My method is annotated as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/keepAlive", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ModelMap test(HttpServletRequest req, final ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("keepAlive", true);
    return model;
}
```

when I call is using ajax using JQuery
it returns 500 server  error and at server log I can see that it is looking for KeepAlive.jsp, I am using spring 3.2.10 and have jackson 2 at class path. When I debugged source code request is passed to **ModelAndViewMethodReturnValueHandler** rather than **RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor** , It seems Model and view handler is registered before req res handler. How to solve this. Same code worked for spring 3.1.2.
Thanks

Comment: It's possible that the fact that you are returning `ModelMap` causes the problem. When using `@ResponseBody` it's more appropriate to return some simple DTO

Comment: It may be, but I am surprised it worked on spring 3.1.2.

Comment: The changes to the code base of Spring MVC from Spring 3.1 to Spring 3.2 where quite extensive, so it may very well be that this behavior was changed

Comment: Spring inspects the return type of the method (not the actual object). Might be, that you should return a DTO... See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9218

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828834/spring-3-2-responsebody-not-working-with-a-model-return-value?rq=1

Comment: Anybody have reference/document to support this change from spring 3.1.2 to 3.2.1o