# Weird Spring MVC 4.2.x behaviour on controller method with ResponseBody and returning Model class instance

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have some legacy controller which puts some amount of data into the `Model` object (needed for Thymeleaf template).

Now I have to return the same data as JSON in REST service.

For these purposes I have wrapped the block of data preparation into separate method to use in two places: in the old method which is used for thymeleaf template and in the new one:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Model model) {
    prepareIndexModel(model);
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/index/model", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> indexModel(Model model) {
    prepareIndexModel(model);
    return model.asMap();
}

private void prepareIndexModel(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("prop1", ...);
    ...
}
```

However, when I try access via `GET /index/model` I receive the following error:

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "/WEB-INF/templates/index/model.html")
```

so it simply considers my method not as REST method. I guess, that it is because method is actually returns instance of `ExtendedModelMap` class which implements both interfaces: `Model` and `Map`.

Therefore, after chaning `/index/model` method to:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index/model", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> indexModel(Model model) {
    prepareIndexModel(model);
    return new LinkedHashMap<>(model.asMap());
}
```

everything started working expected: `GET /index/model` returns me desired JSON. So basically I just wrapped the model into `LinkedHashMap`.

**My question is**: ***is this a specified behaviour or simply a bug?*** I expected that by annotating a method with `@ResponseBody` annotation, Spring should ignore the fact that returning object is instance of `Model`. Shouldn't it?

**UPDATE**: @Sotirios Delimanolis provided the link to the very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828834/spring-3-2-responsebody-not-working-with-a-model-return-value), which was about version 3.2. But my question is **not** about **why**, but is it a **bug** of Spring or is it specified some where in the documentation?

**UPDATE-2**: Please, also note, that in the linked question a method has `Model` returning type, and its behaviour is described. In my case I have `Map<...>` returning type, what in my opinion makes this behaviour strange and inconsistent!

Comment: The linked duplicate was at a time when Spring was still on 3.x. The answer still applies. `getDefaultReturnValueHandlers` registers more or less the same `HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`s in the same order, ie. the one for `Model` before the one for `@ResponseBody`. Also, `asMap` returns a a `Map` that also implements `Model`.

Comment: 1) I am using Spring 4. 2) Have you read my question carefully? I have explicitly emphasised the fact that `model.asMap()` returns object whose class implements `Model` as well

Comment: And as my answer in the duplicate explains, `ModelMethodProcessor` which handles `Model` acts before `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` which handles `@ResponseBody`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis My question was: **is it a bug or specified behaviour**?. I am not asking *why*,because I can actually debug the code and find the reason by myself.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis TBH I did not expect that my `reopen` action will reopen the question. I just wanted to vote for reoppening. Please do not consider this as an offensive action, I really did not expect that my vote will immediately reopen it :-)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Anyway I am appreciated for providing a link to that question. It is enlightening, but unfortunately doesn't answer my question.

Comment: There's no specification as far as I can tell that mentions this order, but the behavior exists over two major versions of the library (I can't speak on it being a bug or not officially, but I don't think so). Both `@ResponseBody` and `Model` have [documented behavior](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types) about what happens when they are returned. They can't both occur.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Please note, that my returning type is `Map<...>` not a `Model`! I would certainly agree that if it would be `Model` that would be explainable, but I have `Map<...>` return type!

Comment: Hmm, got to think about that one.

Comment: Oh yeah, the [`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html#supportsReturnType-org.springframework.core.MethodParameter-) is given the return value, to decide whether it can handle it. `ModelMethodProcessor` can handle a `Model`. (The doc might be misleading with _method return type_. It should probably say _method return value type_.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis so, formally speaking, this a bug, as it contradicts with the documentation, do I correctly understand? Also I would suggest make it an answer (since I hope you would agree that my case as well as emphasis of the question sufficiently differs from that you linked me before in order not to be closed as a duplicate w/o an answer).

Comment: In my opinion, this is a bug in the documentation of `supportsReturnType`, not in the behavior you've witnessed.

Comment: @Andremoniy It doesn't contradict the documentation. If you read the documentation, it says that a return type of `Map` means an implied View with the Map as the Model. It also says that a `@ResponseBody` method means to send the object as the response body, however, that is listed further down, so a strict reading of that would conclude that `Map` return type trumps the `@ResponseBody`. Of course, it never specifies that the list is ordered, so the fact that `Model` trumps `@ResponseBody` trumps `Map`, and that actual return type (not declared return type) matter, is **undefined**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **is this a specified behaviour or simply a bug?**

I would say it's *undefined* behavior.

The [Spring Framework Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-return-types) defines that a return type of `Model` means a View with a Model. It also defines that a return type of `Map` means a View with the Map as the Model. These are both well-defined.

It also specifies that for a method annotated with `@ResponseBody`, the returned value is written to the response HTTP body. Again, this is well-defined.

What it doesn't *specify*, is what happens when a `@ResponseBody` returns a `Model` or a `Map`.

It is very common to return a `Map` to be encoded as JSON, and that works correctly, i.e. `@ResponseBody` takes precedence over return type `Map`. This makes sense.

However, a `Model` is specifically for the purpose of model attributes for a View, so the fact that return type `Model` takes precedence over `@ResponseBody` makes some sense. But as I said, it's not *specified* behavior, but neither is it a bug. It is *undefined*.

If you asked me for what it *should* do, I'd leave it *undefined*, since `Model` as `@ResponseBody` doesn't make any sense to me.

---

Also, the documentation doesn't make the distinction between declared return type and actual return type, so it is *undefined* which is used.

The implementation uses the *actual* return type, which has the advantage that your handler method can return `Object` and then return e.g. a `ModelAndView` or an `HttpEntity`, depending on conditions. This flexibility makes sense, but it isn't explicitly *defined*, as far as I can see.

---

So, result of the combination of `@ResponseBody`, declared return type of `Map`, but actual return type of `Model`, is **undefined**.

If you ask me (and you kind of did), I'd say that *your* code is bugged. If you want to return a `Map` to be sent as the response body, why not just create the `Map` yourself. Asking the Spring framework for a view `Model` makes no sense at all to me.

Even reading the code, I'd be unsure what you actually intended, given the mixed signals of using a `Model` and specifying `@ResponseBody`.

**Conclusion:** Don't be lazy, and create the `Map` yourself.